# A Simple way to force an "Out of Memory" condition?

Tags: ram, syslog

I'm working on getting alerts set up. Can anyone suggest a simple way to force an out of memory condition say on a vanilla ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

If you have root access, yes.

```
sudo mkdir /media/RAM              # Let's make a mount point
sudo mount /dev/ram /media/RAM     # Let's tell the OS to use RAM as storage
cd /media/RAM                      # Let's go to the RAM directory
i=0                                # Let's get an iteration counter
while true       # Let's do something forever (or at least as long as we can)
do               # Do something
  let i=$i+1     # Something is incrementing our iteration counter
  dd if=/dev/zero of=$i bs=10M     # So here's the real work
  sleep 2                          # Ok, OP doesn't like it when his ramhog 
                                   # script runs out of ram (?) So let's slow it down.
done             # Wait a minute, I though we were doing this forever?  How can we be done?
```

So how it works is pretty much spelled out in the comments above.  Just copy and paste this into vi or nano, save it, and run `sudo chmod 755 [filename]`, then run `./[filename]`.  Have fun running out of RAM.

Comment: On an ubuntu system there's no /dev/ram The other small problem above is that the dd has to be run as root, but I can fix that.

Comment: There is a /dev/ram0 so I'll try that.

Comment: And I suppose I have to add to the mount a filesytem type like ramfs?

Comment: Hmmm, you shouldn't have to.  If it wants one, use `-t ramfs`

Comment: The other problem with this I've been experiencing is that changing after running an iteration or two of the loop the box is unusable without a reboot. I was hoping to have something that quickly runs out of memory and doesn't trash the box. I think this solution goes a large part of the way there (after some small fixes), but not quite yet what I had hoped.

Comment: Well, your box will become unusable when you run out of memory.  I've edited it so that it goes slower.

Comment: Hmm... maybe there's a chroot or container kind of solution?

Comment: Perhaps.  I'm not really sure about that.  Why do you need an out of memory situation anyways?  Also, have you tried `memhog`?

Comment: I would like to cause a genuine "Out of memory" condition on a server for testing monitoring. as for _memhog, which one are you thinking of? I have tried https://github.com/Damienkatz/memhog/blob/master/memhog.c and https://gist.github.com/ctran/1d9e7e46991c56797dec they don't cause an "Out of memory" condition more than just a failure to allocate. I might be able to combine the first set of code to reduce usable RAM then use your script, one iteration with drastically less ram. And then afterwards I can free space.

Comment: That might work.  Why are you trying to cause an out of memory condition?